# Рисование в консоли Visual Studio c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Учился писать код в паскале. По ходу учебы перешел на с++ и Visual Studio. В борланд паскале был удобный канвас в котором можно было рисовать фигуры/графики функций etc. есть ли в visual studio аналог?

Comment: Псевдографикой?

Comment: неа, нужно качать дополнительные библиотеки из вне

Comment: @user272591, что за библиотеки?

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan да, почему нет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Windows на окне можно рисовать средствами GDI, консольное окно не исключение. Естественно такое решение будет непереносимым. Пример:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);

    int x = 0;
    for (float i = 0; i < 3.14 * 10; i += 0.05)
    {
        SetPixel(hdc, x, 50 + 25 * cos(i), RGB(255, 255, 255));
        x += 1;
    }

    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кроме установки пикселя в [наличии](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145203(v=vs.85).aspx?ranMID=24542&ranEAID=hL3Qp0zRBOc&ranSiteID=hL3Qp0zRBOc-cn1YWWPy72eVohXLQMUglQ&tduid=(51d7744d480089dfe1fa579f4df044ba)(256380)(2459594)(hL3Qp0zRBOc-cn1YWWPy72eVohXLQMUglQ)()) большое кол-во функций для рисования различных примитивов, с применением разных кистей (толщины, узора и т.п.).

**Внимание! Работает сносно только в старых версиях Windows (Windows XP).** Не использовать для современных систем, начиная с Vista.

Comment: "Внимание! Работает сносно только в старых версиях Windows (Windows XP). " - Вообще-то, работает и в Win7. Естественно, до первого изменения размеров окна.

Comment: Это нигде не работает, у окон есть четко определенный порядок обновления содержимого, вмешиваться в который просто так не следует.

Comment: @VTT, ваш комментарий говорит только о том, что вы не пробовали так делать. Понятно, что рисунок останется только до первой перерисовки консоли, но ничем фатальным это не грозит.

Comment: @insolor Конечно не пробовал, зачем? То, что рисунок может выводится только при особом положении звезд, когда консоль не обновляет своего содержимого делает такой подход совершенно бессмысленным. Можно же нормально рисовать, не опасаясь, что нарисованное чем-то спонтанно перетрётся.