# Построить график функции с помощью символов

Tags: c++, график

Нужно нарисовать график функции в консоли на С++, но проблема в том, что нельзя использовать библиотеки для работы с графикой. То есть нарисовать её нужно с помощью символов (*) и цикла, а я не понимаю, как это сделать.Вот сама функция
exp(x-2)-5*x^2+3

```
#include <iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<cmath>
double foo(const double x)
{
    return exp(x-2)-5*x*x+3;
}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
        int x,a,b,t;
    while (true) {
        std::cout << "Введите диапазон: ";
        std::cin >> a;
        std::cin >> b;
        if (a > b) {
            std::cout << "Ошибка! a > b" << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    while (true) {
        std::cout << "Введите шаг изменения переменной x: ";
        std::cin >> t;
        if (t <=0) {

        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    for (int i = a; i <= b; i +=t) {
        const int y = foo(i);

    }
}
```

Получилось только ось нарисовать.
Функция может возвращать как положительные так и отрицательные значения.

Answer (score 2):

примерно так.
Но под вашу функцию надо оси масштабировать. этим займитесь сами
В общем и целом подход такой - график "рисуется" в двумерном массиве и потом выводится.

```
// размеры "экрана"
// по оси абсцисс    
#define scene_length 150
// по оси ординат 
#define scene_width 40    
  char scene[scene_length][scene_width*2]; // тут будем график рисовать. по оси ординат делаем в 2 раза больше (под отрицательные значения)

  for(int x=0;x<scene_length;x++){ // чистим массив
      for(int y=0;y<scene_width*2;y++)
          scene[x][y]='.';
      scene[x][scene_width]='-'; // это будет абсцисса
  }

  // тут будем обсчитывать функцию и рисовать график
  for(int x=0;x<scene_length;x++){
      double y = 2*x; // моя функция      
      if(abs(y)<scene_width) // проверяем чтобы значение за пределы "экрана" не выходило
          scene[x][(int)round(y-scene_width)]='*'; // ставим точку

  }
  // выводим на экран
  for(int y=scene_width*2-1;y>=0;y--){
      printf ("%03d ", y-scene_width);
      for(int x=0;x<scene_length;x++){
          printf("%c",scene[x][y]);
      }
      printf("\n");
  }

    return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

посмотрите здесь: 
[Рисование в консоли Visual Studio c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/751240/%D0%A0%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8-visual-studio-c)
если у вас windows.

впредь прежде чем задать вопрос попробуйте вначале воспользоваться поиском. что-то вроде такого: "рисование графика в консоли с++".

Comment: задание нарисовать именно псевдографикой